# Compose button with layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Is it possible to create a Button, whose background drawable is a layout?
For example, I would like to create a layout with some horizontal images and some textviews, and all the resulting view should be clickable all at once as a single button.
Would it be possible, and how?

Thank you.

Comment: any view (and therefore layout) can have a onClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_nested_layout);
yourLayout.setOnclickListener(...);
```